# How to move or download the twilio recording to amazon s3

Tags: twilio

How to download the recording file using twilio sdk or how to move the recording file directly from twilio to amazon s3 .

Answer (score 5):

Twilio evangelist here.

Recordings are exposed via a direct URL, so in order to download them you'll need to use a the HTTP Client in your programming language of choice to make a GET request to the recording URL and save the data that is returned.

There are two ways to find out the URL:

1. If you specifya URL in the [action parameter of the `<Record>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-action) Twilio will make an HTTP request to that URL once the recording is complete and include as a parameter the URL that the recording has been stored at.
2. Make a [GET request to the recordings resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording#list) of the Twilio REST API.  This will return to you a list of recording resources, each of which has a URI parameter included in it.  Add .mp3 or .wav to that URI to get the URL needed to request the recorded audio.

Once you've downloaded the recording, you can use the REST API to have Twilio delete it from our servers.  Just issue an [HTTP DELETE](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording#instance-delete) request to the recordings uri.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah , thank you for your reply . But instead of downloading the twilio audio , i need to move to AWS s3 directly . Is there any option ..?

Comment: Current Scenario : we are downloading from recording from twilio to our server and made a s3 mount to one of the s3 bucket .
 Needed Scenario : Instead of downloading the recording from twilio to our local server . I need to move/copy the recording file direct from twilio s3 to my account AWS S3.

Comment: Devin, I am new to Twilio and trying your suggestion. I am using <Response>
    <Record timeout="10" transcribe="true" action="https://testurl.com/abc /> </Response> to post the recording to external URL.This is not working.Could you please refer any tutorial to achieve this.I was trying to post recording to my custom external API to collect it in my remote code

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Ruby script I wrote to do this. For fastest results, run this from a server and copy to a bucket in US East, which is where Twilio is. I just did this from a Heroku app, since Heroku is in US East. Run `heroku run bash -a my-app-name`. Install the gems:

```
gem install twilio-ruby aws-sdk --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Then fire up irb and run this code (updating your credentials and bucket name).

```
require 'twilio-ruby'
account_sid = 'your_account_sid'
auth_token = 'your_auth_token'
twilio_rest_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

require 'aws-sdk'
access_key_id = 'your_access_key_id'
secret_access_key = 'your_secret_access_key'
region = 'us-east-1'
bucket = 'your-bucket-name'
Aws.config.update({
  region: region,
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(access_key_id, secret_access_key)
})
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: region)

recordings = twilio_rest_client.account.recordings.list(page_size: 1000)

begin
  begin
    recordings.each do |recording|
      recording.mp3! do |file|
        begin
          path = recording.mp3.gsub('https://api.twilio.com/', '')
          object = s3.bucket(bucket).object(path)
          object.put(body: file.body)
        rescue Aws::S3::Errors::ServiceError => error
          puts error.message
          puts recording.mp3
        end
      end
      recording.delete
    end
  rescue Twilio::REST::RequestError => error
    puts error.message
    puts recording.mp3
  end

  recordings = recordings.next_page
end while !recordings.empty?
```